# Receipt OCR & Personal Finance Management app for Android?

Tags: android, collaboration, ocr, finance, camera

Is there and app (preferably for Android or Linux) that would support receipt OCR, so I could just take photos of receipts after shopping? (preferably with option to collaborate with other people, like for team or home spending?)

I imagine following workflow:

- make photo of receipt
- **Main requirement** : it's automatically **OCR** **into** **list of** bought **items** and their price
  (list of items on receipt! not just total price!)
- I can edit / fix receipt (in case of mistakes by OCR)
- preferably program learns how same things are called on receipts from different shops
- later I can analyze aggregates (from week, month) (and preferably export)
- collaboration functionality highly welcome (imagine team, when people add their spending, or a couple running their household)

This video a kind of represents the idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDxsedCh8Ig

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially make clear what your requirements are (must-haves and nice-to-haves). For Android, there are several [budget apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=50) working in a comparable way (scan+OCR); not sure about sharing, though.

Comment: What language? OCR for Polish is quite different from OCR for Japanese.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Preferably: German, English, Polish, French, Italian - same alphabet :)

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: Good OCR uses a grammar/dictionary to guess words better. For instance `Najwjększym` would get fixed to `Największym` automatically.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul That's why I look for OCR+receipt which will adopt to words which will see on receipts, allowibg me to type and correct to provide it feedvack for self-learning/improving recognition (collecting training samples). Btw. good OCR is capable to select dictionary for each scan or even guess which is most appropriate.

Comment: More alternatives here: [Shopping Receipts](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/shopping_receipts). Not using any of those, I cannot give a direct recommendation – but a "concentrated list" with reviews linked might be helpful, though :)

Answer (score 4):

**[Receipts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rocklab.abc.android.Receipts)**

Pros:

- OCR understanding receipts
- Offline OCR!
- low privileges requirement
- Export options (Dropbox, Google Docs)

Cons:

- Can not supply photo from gallery (have to make new each time)
- Couldn't figure out how to add all things from receipt at once, instead of one thing with every photo
- A part from this , a kind of simple app.

Conclusion:

- If your needs are simple, and you just don't want to type receipts, this might be for you!
- UI feels cranky and I had problem to force this app to consume even simple receipts with fee items

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put in answering. (Un)fortunately, our quality requirements for answer are quite hard. Please edit you interesting contributions to fit in: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality

Comment: @VicAche I hope now it's better :)

Answer (score 3):

**[Receipts by Wave](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waveaccounting.receipts)**
Wave HQ  - January 3, 2014
Finance

Prons:

- OCR of Receipts!
- Nice UI
- Exporting to Google Drive, Dropbox...
- separate private and business accounting in same app

Cons:

- require more privileges that such app might need to require...
- need to make an account with them to try OCR as it has to send photo and they do OCR remotely
- ONLY consumes total amount of whole receipt! I haven't figure out how to make it turn receipt into list of items.

Conclusion:

- fancy but very simple after all - for each receipt just name of shop and total amount, I was expecting list of items...
- Therefore, for my requirement of **list of items** - this app is useless. However, If you are fine with just totals of receipts, it's good app to go.

Comment: Here is suggestion on their website: https://support.waveapps.com/entries/40322880-OCR-of-Receipts-extracting-Line-Items